# How to always fill the parent height using flexbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="admonition info">
  <p class="admonition-title">Info</p>
  <p>Text here</p>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.admonition {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.admonition > p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  display: block;
}

.admonition-title {
  background-color: #2B83BD;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
}

.admonition > .admonition-title {
  font-size: 1px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: transparent;
  width: 64px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-width: 60px;
}

.admonition > .admonition-title:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #fff;
}

.admonition.info > .admonition-title:before {
  content: "\f129";
}

.admonition.info > p:not(.admonition-title) {
  background-color: #7DBAE3;
}

.admonition.info > .admonition-title {
  background-color: #2B83BD;
}
```

I would like to render the children with the following constraints:

- They are vertically centered
- If their height is not equal, they should stretch to fill the gaps

[image: Current rendering]

The white gaps are what I would like to avoid. <kbd>[Live on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2g7Ljbd/)</kbd>

The HTML is generated from markdown and I don't really have control over the structure. Is this possible to implement in a simple way? Javascript, jquery is also OK, but I'd prefer to do this in CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `align-items: stretch;` to make the items fill the parent height.

Then, your icon will need to be centered manually, I have done it with:

```
.admonition > .admonition-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4mw8a08x/

[image]

Comment: Is there anything else you changed? If I only change that, I get this rendering: http://i.imgur.com/19wrLOs.png ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqvc9ybt/1/))

Comment: Yes, if you look at my jsfiddle, I have made some other little changes to align properly the "icon".

Comment: Thanks for the added details, now I get it.